# Why isn't my ErrorView rendering in tests?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I’m currently trying to test the update function of my controller, which looks like this:

```
def update(conn, params = %{"id" => id}) do
  lesson_params = Map.delete(params, "id")
  lesson = Lessons.get_lesson!(id)
  with {:ok, %Lesson{} = lesson} <- Lessons.update_lesson(lesson, lesson_params) do
    json(conn, LessonSerializer.to_map(lesson))
  end
end
```

Where things are breaking down is in my update 404 test. When I call the controller function, I’m getting an `Ecto.NoResultsError` falling through.

```
put(build_conn(), lesson_path(build_conn(), :update, Ecto.UUID.generate), %{})
```

From what I understand, my `ErrorView` should have kicked in to render a proper response, but that doesn’t seem to be happening in my testing environment. Instead, the exception falls all the way through. My `ErrorView` works fine in `dev` when I set `debug_errors` to `false.`

Should the `ErrorView` be working in tests? Or am I missing something here? If this is expected, is there any way to enable `ErrorView` for the tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think Phoenix will render an error view unless you tell it to.

I personally am not a fan of the "raise if not found" approach, but I think you have to try/rescue that and explicitly render the error view. The other approach would be to use the "non-bang" version of the query (ie: `get` instead of `get!`) and render the error view if you get nil.

There is one bit of "magic" that you can use though: the FallbackController. You wire this up with `action_fallback/1`. The docs cover this nicely, including an example implementation of a FallbackController:

https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.Controller.html#action_fallback/1

Basically, your `with` block tries to match on the "ok tuple" and it will return whatever it gets that doesn't match (as opposed to throwing a no-match error). Phoenix expects the action to return a `conn` so wiring up the action_fallback tells it what to do if it doesn't get a conn.

I think you would need to change `Lessons.update_lesson/2` to return an error rather than raise... something like `{:error, :not_found}` would be standard practice and is covered in that example in the docs.

Note that generally speaking you would just make one FallbackController that all your controllers use to handle their error cases.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer! I started down the road of using a FallbackController and returning the error code, but I felt like the code was getting messy with the conditionals and nesting. Maybe I'm just used to Rails, but I've always liked not having to worry too much about it when building my controllers. Do you know if there's a way to wire up the ErrorView so it renders in tests? I feel like I'm mixing the crux of *why* the `ErrorView` doesn't render in tests. It's feeling a little too magical to me at the moment.

Comment: I'm pretty sure your test is showing that you have a bug: you have to handle error cases some way or another! There is basically no magic in Phoenix at all. The only thing that comes close is controllers selecting a view based on the action name. What happens if you try to update a non-existent record through the UI?

Comment: Also, you shouldn't need *any* conditionals in a FallbackController. You just need one function head per error. Check that example in the docs!

Comment: If there's a bug, shouldn't calls directly to the dev server also be failing? Right now, if I call `PUT /lessons:id` from the CLI with a generated UUID, the server properly 404s and gives me the correct response from my `ErrorView`. Is this expected behavior for my test suite? As for the conditionals, I was referring more to the nested conditions in my controller's `update` function. Thanks again!

Comment: The beauty of the FallbackController approach is you shouldn't need more conditionals in the controller action. You can just make the first clause of the `with` be looking up the record and the second updating it. If the first clause gets nil instead of the record, the `with` won't execute the second block and will just return the error. Then the FallbackController matches on that error and renders the error view.

Comment: HOWEVER, after thinking about this more (and looking at some old code of mine) I think there is a way of wiring up NoResultsError to return a 404. If your code works outside tests then that's probably what it's doing. I'll try to dig that up....

Comment: Ahah! This post covers how this works: https://tomalexhughes.com/blog/handling-errors-in-phoenix-applications
There is a `render_errors` option on the Endpoint config. That tells it to use your ErrorView. Sorry for misleading you... and sorry that I'm still not sure why your 404 test isn't working.

Comment: I think generally that `render_errors` is only wired up in dev/prod, not tests, and then you use `assert_error_sent` in tests: https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.ConnTest.html#assert_error_sent/2